# XStream And Proguard

Tags: android, xstream

I am using xstream-android.jar for multiple tasks in my Android project. But when i release it then it comes that proguard do usual optimizations and obfuscation. Since i am using XStream and let them parse XML into list of POJO's to work with ease with the XML i run into the problem that XStream won't work properly with proguard.

`08-19 03:39:25.440: W/System.err(1522): com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: HospitalCode : Didn't find class "HospitalCode" on path: /data/app/com.mobilefh.medicalregister-1.apk
08-19 03:39:25.440: W/System.err(1522): ---- Debugging information ----
08-19 03:39:25.440: W/System.err(1522): message             : HospitalCode : Didn't find class "HospitalCode" on path: /data/app/com.mobilefh.medicalregister-1.apk
08-19 03:39:25.440: W/System.err(1522): cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
08-19 03:39:25.440: W/System.err(1522): cause-message       : HospitalCode : Didn't find class "HospitalCode" on path: /data/app/com.mobilefh.medicalregister-1.apk
08-19 03:39:25.440: W/System.err(1522): class               : java.util.List
08-19 03:39:25.440: W/System.err(1522): required-type       : com.mobilefh.medicalregister.b.b.f
08-19 03:39:25.440: W/System.err(1522): path                : /list/Hospital/HospitalCode
08-19 03:39:25.440: W/System.err(1522): -------------------------------`
I'm experimenting around with the proguard options to no let xstream work like:

-libraryjars libs/xstream-android.jar
-keep class com.thoughtworks.xstream.**{*;}

I am very thankful if someone has suggestions how to solve that. To get XStream working with proguard.

Thanks in advance

wikistar

Comment: Proguard probably obfuscated (read: renamed) your POJOs and its fields, which means XStream is no longer able to match the XML tags against them. You'll need to exclude anything that needs to be mapped from xml to POJOs in your Proguard config file. Or said differently: ensure you exclude every class that has XStream annotations.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I deal with XStream 1.4.7 and Proguard. Add the following 2 lines in `proguard-project.txt` file:

```
-keep class com.thoughtworks.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.thoughtworks.**
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you first try to check with de-compile your apk file and double check if the class HospitalCode is really there?

Then I think the most possible answer is that you did not include the whole JAR file in your release version of APK.

Comment: HospitalCode is String type.The apk runs well without proguard. The whold JAR file is included, i think.

Comment: Did you try to decompile you APK and see if class "HospitalCode" is there? This is to confirm if this class is 'optimized' by proguard.

Comment: In my source code , there is no HospitalCode class. The "HospitalCode" is just a String definded in a Class like this:<br/>`private String HospitalCode;
 private String HospitalName;`

Comment: But in the trace you provided, the runtime is complaining about: Didn't find class "HospitalCode". So, can you decompile your APK to find the key word "HospitalCode"?

Comment: I decompile the apk, and can not find the class "HospitalCode". In my source code, there is no 'HospitalCode' indeed. I am confused that why the runtime complains that.

Comment: As you said, there is no such class. So, did you find the keyword? Where is it? Is it same as you stated as a string variable?

Comment: As above mationed, the "HospitalCode" is definded in a class as a regular field.

Comment: Do you mean that from the decompiled APK source code, you can see something like "private String HospitalCode = null;" and you got such error?

Comment: No. I mean in my project source code, I declare the field in a class. Now the problem is solved. As MT said, the proguard obfuscates the source code and  XStream is no longer able to match the XML tags against them. By keeping the class where "HospitalCode" is definded from obfuscated, it runs well.

Comment: Thanks. And I remember sometimes I also get similar error when I declare the button on click call back in the layout XML file.